# Reference with resources not following (Visual Studio)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reference

I have a dll that I have made that works perfectly.  I need to make some changes to it however so I simply made a console application to run it for trouble shooting it.  The console application references the dll and simply calls it to run, then waits for user input.  The dll is copied to the directory with the console app and everyone is happy.  Except for the fact that the resources from the dll do NOT go with it.  How can I remedy this problem?  thanks for your help!

**edit:**  I solved the problem this time because I found that the data was already being copied to a common directory any ways, but I would still like to know other ideas that I could use in the case where this wouldn't fall into place nicely with other projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are the resources that you're expecting actually part of the DLL, or are they in another file (a ".resources" file or an accompanying EXE)? The first thing I'd suspect is that those resources are in a separate file aside from the DLL and just aren't being copied over.

Comment: it is one XML file and one Config file.  Both are needed for the dll to properly run.  I have them set to copy to output directory always, but that only gets them to the output directory with the dll, not beyond.  Is there a fix for this, or do I have to manually copy them?

Comment: I have accepted this answer simply because no other answer came out of this question.  I am just going based on the assumption that what I was trying to do doesn't work.  If this assumption is false please let me know.